# The class is not uploadable. If you use attributes to configure VichUploaderBundle, you probably just forgot to add `#[Vich\\Uploadable]`

Tags: doctrine-orm, api-platform.com, vichuploaderbundle

I am trying to set up uploading to an API Platform server using this documentation:

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/file-upload/

However, following all of these steps gives me an error when trying to upload using curl.

```
curl -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@/XXXXX/something.png" https://localhost/media_objects
```

```json
{
"@context":"/contexts/Error",
"@type":"hydra:Error",
"hydra:title":"An error occurred",
"hydra:description":"The class \u0022App\Entity\MediaObject\u0022 is not uploadable. If you use attributes to configure VichUploaderBundle, you probably just forgot to add #[Vich\\Uploadable] on top of your entity. If you don\u0027t use attributes, check that the configuration files are in the right place. In both cases, clearing the cache can also solve the issue."
}
......
```

The important part:

**The class \u0022App\Entity\MediaObject\u0022 is not uploadable. If you use attributes to configure VichUploaderBundle, you probably just forgot to add #[Vich\Uploadable] on top of your entity. If you don\u0027t use attributes, check that the configuration files are in the right place. In both cases, clearing the cache can also solve the issue.**

My code was pulled fully from API Platform's example:

```php
<?php
// api/src/Entity/MediaObject.php
namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Post;
use ApiPlatform\OpenApi\Model;
use App\Controller\CreateMediaObjectAction;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

#[Vich\Uploadable]
#[ORM\Entity]
#[ApiResource(
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['media_object:read']], 
    types: ['https://schema.org/MediaObject'],
    operations: [
        new Get(),
        new GetCollection(),
        new Post(
            controller: CreateMediaObjectAction::class, 
            deserialize: false, 
            validationContext: ['groups' => ['Default', 'media_object_create']], 
            openapi: new Model\Operation(
                requestBody: new Model\RequestBody(
                    content: new \ArrayObject([
                        'multipart/form-data' => [
                            'schema' => [
                                'type' => 'object', 
                                'properties' => [
                                    'file' => [
                                        'type' => 'string', 
                                        'format' => 'binary'
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ])
                )
            )
        )
    ]
)]
class MediaObject
{
    #[ORM\Id, ORM\Column, ORM\GeneratedValue]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ApiProperty(types: ['https://schema.org/contentUrl'])]
    #[Groups(['media_object:read'])]
    public ?string $contentUrl = null;

    #[Vich\UploadableField(mapping: "media_object", fileNameProperty: "filePath")]
    #[Assert\NotNull(groups: ['media_object_create'])]
    public ?File $file = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)] 
    public ?string $filePath = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

And as you can clearly see we have the proper attribute and include:

```
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

#[Vich\Uploadable]
```

and our VICH yaml config is set to use attributes:

```yaml
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    metadata:
        type: attribute
    mappings:
        media_object:
            uri_prefix: /media
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/media'
            # Will rename uploaded files using a uniqueid as a prefix.
            namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\OrignameNamer
```

So why am I getting the error? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a gotcha for VICH Bundle and Doctrine 2.8+

https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/docs/known_issues.md#doctrineannotations-package-required-when-using-doctrine-bundle--28

> Doctrine/annotations package required when using doctrine-bundle >=
> 2.8 If your project is using doctrine-bundle:>=2.8, you must require doctrine/annotations package from your project as it is not required
> in doctrine-bundle anymore from this version. This bundle is using a
> Reader interface from this package in order to work for both
> annotations and attributes mapping.

So in my case the solution was simply including the `doctrine-annotations` bundle in my docker api platform implementation:

`docker compose exec php composer require  doctrine/annotations`